# mySQL - query to combine two tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables. The first one holds information about cities:

Locations:

```
locID     |   locationID    |  locationName    |  countryCode    |
1         |      2922239    |     Berlin       |      de         |
2         |      291074     |     Paris        |      fr         |
3         |      295522     |    Orlando       |      us         |
3         |      292345     |    Tokyo         |      jp         |
```

There is a second table, which holds alternative names for locations. There might be NO alternative name for a location in the Locations table:
AlternateNames:

```
altNameID |   locationID    |  alternateName    |
1         |      2922239    |     Berlino       | 
2         |      2922239    |     Berlina       |
3         |      2922239    |     capital       |
4         |      291074     |     Parisa        |
5         |      291074     |     Pariso        | 
6         |      295522     |     Orlandola     |
7         |      295522     |     Orlandolo     |
```

What I would like to get is the locationID, name and the countryCode of a location for a location name search like "Berlin", or "Ber":

```
|   locationID   |   name       |  countryCode    |
|   2922239      |   Berlin     |        de       |
```

However, if the user searches for "Berlino", I would like to get the alternateName back:

```
|   locationID   |   name       |  countryCode    |
|   2922239      |   Berlino    |        de       |
```

The "locationName" has a higher priority than the alternateName, if the searchterm matches both.

I can't figure out how to build a query to do that. Since the name can come from one of the two tables, it seems quite difficult to me.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   locationID, 
   (IF (name LIKE 'Ber%', name, alternateName)) as name, 
   countryCode 
FROM
   Locations l LEFT JOIN AlternateNames a ON (l.locationID = a.locationID)
WHERE
  name LIKE 'Ber%'
OR
  alternateName LIKE 'Ber%'
```

Obviously, use variable substitution (:searchname) in place of 'Ber%'.

Add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query if you only want 1 row returned.

Edited based on comment about preference for alternateName.  Made LEFT join per Schultz999 suggestion

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm looking for "Berlino%" I would still get "Berlin" as locationName

Comment: @W.Gerick: James is looking for 'Ber'. If you are looking for 'Berlino', the query will return 'Berlino'. And it was made clear when he said you needed to replace the search string with a variable.

Comment: @James: the only correction I'd made is LEFT JOIN the tables because there might be no alternatives to the name.

Comment: @James: btw, it still need some correction in regard of priority. Consider the case in the question: Berlin vs Berlino. The search string is Ber so the main name, Berlin, must be returned. However in your case (IF (alternateName LIKE 'Ber%', alternateName, name)) will result alternative name instead.

Comment: @Schultz9999 ha, you're right I had the IF backwards. Thanks, fixed

Comment: @James: it's all good but there is a major problem though :) Imaging the main name is very different from the alternative, which is very easy for the different languages. So let main is ABC and the alternative is XYZ. If the search string is 'X', which technically should return XYZ, the actual result will be empty, because the main table won't have matches and thus LEFT JOIN won't even be tried.

Comment: @Schultz9999 I don't think so, the query as is would match X if there is an alternateName matching X because the WHERE clause includes both name and alternateName; the IF statement would provide the alternateName, XYZ if name (ABC) doesn't match X

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! This works almost perfectly. One issue: If I substitute the searchterm for 'Orlando%' for example, I get two hits. Maybe grouping by l.locationID ?.

Comment: You could add LIMIT 1 to the end of the query if you only want 1 row

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do this.

```
select a.locationID, coalesce(b.alternateName,a.locationName), a.countrycode FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.locationId=B.locationID where a.locationName=?
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this query there is no way to search for an alternateName like "Berlino"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<del>SELECT a.locationID, :locationName, a.countryCode // :locationName being the city name parameter
      FROM cities a, locations b
     WHERE a.locationID = b.locationID
       AND (a.locationName = :locationName OR b.alternateName =  :locationName )</del>

```
SELECT a.locationID, a.locationName, a.countryCode 
  FROM cities a
 WHERE a.locationName = :locationName
 UNION ALL
SELECT a.locationID, b.alternateName locationName, a.countryCode
  FROM cities a, locations b
 WHERE a.locationID = b.locationID
   AND b.alternateName =  :locationName
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm looking for "Berlin" I would get two hits. Also, searching for "Berlino" would return "Berlin".

Comment: As long as there are no alternatives matching the orignal, it should work just fine. But you need to use LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

This query joins the two tables via a union query, ranks them and takes the top result from the union.

Try this:

```
SELECT
      locationID
    , `name`
    , countryCode
FROM
    (
        SELECT
                  locationID
                , `name`
                , countryCode
                , 1 AS priority
        FROM
            locations
        WHERE
            locationName LIKE 'Ber%'
        UNION
            SELECT
                  a.locationID
                , a.alternateName AS `name`
                , l.countryCode
                , 2 as priority
            FROM
                AlternateNames a
                INNER JOIN Locations l
                    ON a.locationID = l.locationID
            WHERE
                a.alternateName LIKE 'Ber%'
    ) u
ORDER BY
    priority
LIMIT 1
```